# What are good references for dynamic pricing?

Tags: time-series, references, algorithms, operations-research

I think that dynamic pricing algorithms (used in aviation and ticketing industry) is very statistical based, anyone here has experience with those algorithms with references for it?

Answer (score 4):

This article is highly cited:

"Yield Management at American Airlines" by Barry C. Smith et al.

Links:

- [JSTOR](http://www.jstor.org/stable/25061571)
- [free PDF 1](http://www2.haut.edu.cn/jpkc2006/orsite/c/case/c28.pdf), broken at 06.09.12
- [free PDF 2](http://morten.ifi.uio.no/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/Smith_et_al_yield_mgmnt.pdf), broken at 02.01.18
- [free PDF 3](https://classes.engineering.wustl.edu/2010/fall/ese403/software/Informs%20Articles/CH18%20Yield%20Management%20at%20American%20Airlines.pdf)